# Include Inline Source and Sourcemap from node_modules in webpack 2 build

Tags: angular, build, webpack, source-maps

I have a project structure the looks like the following.

```
--Module UI
  --Node_Modules
      --Module Shared
--Module Shared
```

Module UI - The UI module which is build using webpack. It has a local npm reference to Module Auth.

Module Shared - The Shared module is a common module which is shared. It is complied with the tsc command and exposes its complied javascript and typescript mappings for use in other projects. It uses the following tsconfig.json options.

```
"inlineSourceMap": true,
"inlineSources": true,
```

This results in the javascript files it complies having the following sourceMappingURL's.

```
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64 [BASE64 Encoded Source map and source.]
```

If I include the javascript files directly in another project the source maps and source work as expected. I am unable to find a way to include them in my webpack build so that the source maps are debuggable in a packed build.

Does anyone see anything I should change or have suggestions to make this work?

npm command to build

```
"build": "rimraf dist && rimraf wwwroot && webpack --config webpack.dev.js --progress --profile --bail"
```

webpack.dev.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./config/helpers.js');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'dev';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('wwwroot'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js',
        sourceMapFilename: '[name].js.map'
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
            mangle: {
                keep_fnames: true
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
            }
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            htmlLoader: {
                minimize: false // workaround for ng2
            }
        })
    ],

    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal'
    }
});
```

webpack.common.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./config/helpers.js');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'auth': './node_modules/CFPet.Auth/dist/app.auth.module.js',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: ["source-map-loader"],
                enforce: "pre"
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallbackLoader: 'style-loader', loader: 'css-loader?sourceMap' })
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'auth','vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```